# I have problems for consuming web service in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight-2.0

my problem is as follows:
When I use my web service, it displays the following error in Silverlight:

```
"System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException was unhandled by user code
  Message="The given key was not present in the dictionary."
```

I'm new to c # and Silverlight, and don't really know what to do. I can not find a solution on Google.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code? Kind of hard to help otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Friends found the problem was not using the namespace "System.ServiceModel" 
link where I explained some of this here [link text](http://silverlight.net/learn/learnvideo.aspx?video=47177)